# Custom view confuses the layout of surrounding views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have trouble to properly layout a custom view.
The view is very simple but override `onMeasure` to always be **square**, i.e. height and width should always be the same.

My problem is that any surrounding views become confused and does not properly size themselves.

The expected result:
[image: Expected result]

This is the result using LinearLayout:
[image: Using LinearLayout]

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
    <example.Square
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:color="@color/black" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result using RelativeLayout:
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
      android:id="+@id/edittext1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <example.Square
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edittext1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:color="@color/black" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is code for the Custom View:

```
public class Square extends View {

  private Paint paint;

  protected void init() {
    paint = new Paint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor( android.R.color.black));
  }

  public Square( Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
  }

  public Square( Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context,attributeSet);
    init();
  }

  public int getColor() {
    return paint.getColor();
  }

  public void setColor(int color) {
    paint.setColor(color);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int l = Math.min(getMeasuredHeight(),getMeasuredWidth());
    setMeasuredDimension(l,l);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas ) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if ( (getWidth() > 0) && (getHeight() > 0) ) {
      RectF r = new RectF( getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getWidth()-getPaddingRight(), getHeight()-getPaddingBottom() );
      canvas.drawRect( r, paint );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try to `Log.d` the value of `int l`?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a `RelativeLayout` you're telling the `EditText` to take as much place as possible with `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and then display your square to the right of it. I think you should change layout rules to display the square and then fill available place with the `EditText`. I think something likes this will work:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="+@id/edittext1"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/square"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <example.Square
            android:id="+@id/square"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:color="@color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```